# Can't access written files on windows

Tags: android, sd-card, galaxy, filewriter

I wrote a logfile to my sd (internal storage of the Samsung Galaxy Nexus). Actually the file is invisible in windows. How can I let users access them?

```
    this.state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

Returns "mounted"

This is my Code:

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of Logger
 * 
 * */
public Logger() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();
    this.file = new File(path, "log.txt");
}



/**
 * Writes results to log file
 * 
 * **/
public void log(boolean isConnected, int signalStrength) {

    try {
        this.buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.file, true));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        String result = time.getTime().toString() + " "
                + String.valueOf(isConnected) + " "
                + String.valueOf(signalStrength);

        this.buf.write(result);

        this.buf.flush();
        this.buf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It won't write anything (even though I receive no exception).
Manifest contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Edit:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsoluteFile();
```

Didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The file is there, but it has not been picked up by the MediaScanner yet. You can verify by opening a shell like so:

```
adb shell ls -l /mnt/sdcard/clown.txt
```

You need to either wait for it to be picked up, reboot, or (preferably), call [MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) when you are done writing to the file.

Comment: You're right. I have to get MediaScannerConnection running and this will be solved.